# Keeping parent page active in menu, when on a child page

Tags: wordpress

I've created the page "press" child of media page (parent).
when i'm on press page, the parent page (media) in menu doesn't remain active.

Comment: If you are using a standard WordPress menu the parent li container should get the following classes "current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent" when you are on the child page - so just make use of those in your CSS

Comment: thx @SimonPollard :)

Comment: Hope that helped @manu I have added it as an actual answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a standard WordPress menu the parent li container should get the following classes "current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent" when you are on the child page - so just make use of those in your CSS